# Passing boolean values with wp_localize_script

Tags: jquery, theme-options, wp-localize-script

I am using wp_localize_script to pass a couple of values from my theme options to a javascript file. First I got the values from my theme options:

```
$options = get_option('theme');  
$flex_auto = $options["slide-auto"];
$flex_animation = $options["slide-animation"];
$flex_direction = $options["slide-direction"];
```

Then I used `wp_localize_script` to create my array of values.

```
wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
wp_localize_script('flexslider', 'flex_vars', array(
    'flex_auto' => $flex_auto,
    'flex_animation' => $flex_animation,
        'flex_direction' => $flex_direction
    )
);
```

In my javascript file I did this:

```
var $anim = flex_vars.flex_animation;
var $auto = flex_vars.flex_auto;
var $dire = flex_vars.flex_direction;

jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: $anim,
    slideshow: $auto,
    controlNav: 'thumbnails',
    directionNav: $dire, 
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    touch: true,
});
```

My theme options include some values that are made with checkboxes which work with 0/1 booleans while the jQuery plugin I'm using works with true/false. I tried saving the boolean value as strings by using a drop-down menu with two options, either true or false, but that doesn't seem to work. How can I pass the boolean values from the theme options to the javascript file? Any suggestions and hints very welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$options = get_option( 'theme' );

wp_localize_script( 'flexslider', 'flex_vars', array (
  'flex_auto' => ($options['slide-auto']) ? 'true' : 'false',
  'flex_animation' => $options['slide-animation'],
  'flex_direction' => $options['slide-direction']
) );
```

Assuming `slide-auto` is the option you made a boolean.

*This script isn't tested, I directly typed it in here.*

Comment: Ok tried it and I had to remove the little apostrophies around true and false. So it looks more like this now: `'flex_auto' => ($options['slide-auto']) ? true : false,` Thanks so much!

Comment: For just forcing type to boolean better way to write it would be with `(bool) $options['slide-auto']` cast.

Comment: Worth noting that in my wp 3.8.1 I get not strictly true or false, but "1" or "": `var PARAMS = {"true":"1","false":""};`

Comment: To avoid the stringification of the cast values you can use a nested array - see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/186191/57034.

Comment: Variables "localized" this way will always be casted to string in JS. If you need proper bools or integers, this wont work.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @bonger in the comment.

If you need boolean or integer values in the wp_localize_script function, you need to place them in a nested array.

```php
wp_localize_script( 'script-handle', 'jsVariableName', [
    'args' => [
        'boolValue'      => true,
        'boolValueFalse' => false,
        'intValue'       => 9,
        'floatValue'     => 10.3,
        'stringValue'    => 'some string',
    ],
] );
```

This will result in this in your JS script.

```js
{
    args: {
        boolValue: true
        boolValueFalse: false
        floatValue: 10.3
        intValue: 9
        stringValue: "some string"
    }
}
```

All the variables in the first level of your array will be converted to string (well, this is an i18n method).

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer working for me

```
wp_add_inline_script('helloworld','var site_config ='.json_encode(array (<Your array>)));
```

[wp_localize_script with boolean and init](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237854/wp-localize-script-with-boolean-and-init)