# How do you pass a boolean value to wp_localize_script

Tags: wp-localize-script

What is the best way to pass a *boolean*  into wp_localize_script as from what I can see everything is interpretted as strings.

I have a backend user options form for a plugin, when the values are returned I am using them for a jQuery script, one of them is a boolean, the user selects true or false from a dropdown, using wp_localize_script outputs these as strings (not booleans) "true" or "false" which will fail that parameter in the script.

```
<?php

  $options = get_option('ng_slicknavmenu');
  // Add PHP plugin variables to the $params[] array to pass to jQuery
  $data = array (
    'ng_slicknav_menu'         => $options['ng_slicknav_menu'],
    'ng_slicknav_parent_links' => $options['ng_slicknav_parent_links'], // this is a boolean true/false
    'ng_slicknav_speed'        => $options['ng_slicknav_speed'] ,
  );

  // Pass PHP variables to jQuery script
  wp_localize_script( 'slickinit', 'phpVars', $data );
```

This is how I am doing it at the moment in my js init file

```
   if( phpVars.ng_slicknav_parent_links === "true" )
        $links = true;
    else
        $links = false;


jQuery(document).ready(function($){

ng_slicknav_speedInt = parseInt(phpVars.ng_slicknav_speed, 10);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(phpVars.ng_slicknav_menu).slicknav({
                allowParentLinks: $links,
                duration:ng_slicknav_speedInt,
            });
            });
 });
```

But is there a better way?

I have tried some solutions from [Passing boolean values with wp_localize_script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105426/passing-boolean-values-with-wp-localize-script) ...

```
'ng_slicknav_parent_links' => ($options['ng_slicknav_parent_links']) ? true : false,
```

and

```
'ng_slicknav_parent_links' => (bool)$options['ng_slicknav_parent_links'],
```

But the answer does not work. The answers there for both result in a string of "1" for both values which is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately `wp_localize_script()` casts all scalars (simple types) in the passed-in array to strings (and then runs `html_entity_decode()` on them?!), so the casts mentioned by the answer you quote & @TheDeadMedic will get stringified "1"/"" if boolean, and number strings if ints, which won't work with javascript plugins that demand exact values.

A way around it is to put your arguments in an array within the passed-in array, then they don't get mangled, eg:

```
$data = array (
    'ng_slicknav' => array(
        'menu'         => $options['ng_slicknav_menu'],
        'parent_links' => (bool) $options['ng_slicknav_parent_links'],
        'speed'        => (int) $options['ng_slicknav_speed'] ,
    ),
);
```

And you can reference them directly in your javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(phpVars.ng_slicknav.menu).slicknav({
        allowParentLinks: phpVars.ng_slicknav.parent_links,
        duration:phpVars.ng_slicknav.speed,
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work as boolean comes in as a string
 `/* <![CDATA[ */
var phpVars = {"ng_slicknav":{"menu":"#menu-secondary-navigation","allowParentLinks":"true","duration":"400"}};
/* ]]> */`

Comment: Are the options typed correctly? If not try doing the casts as suggested (`'allowParentLinks' => (bool) $options['ng_slicknav_parent_links'], 'd‌uration' => (int) $options['ng_slicknav_speed']`).

Comment: ok now both the boolean and integer are returned correctly but the menu doesn't fire, I assume its to do with the nested array, I can see the values OK
`/* <![CDATA[ */
var phpVars = {"ng_slicknavmenu":{"ng_slicknav_menu":"#menu-primary-navigation-1","prependTo":"body","allowParentLinks":true,"showChildren":true,"duration":400,"label":"MENUGEDD0N"}};
/* ]]> */`

Comment: Here is a gist [link]https://gist.github.com/neilgee/9bb8d424b4a0a7f2e325

Comment: Yes as you have it in Example 2 in the gist you need to refer to `phpVars.ng_slicknav.ng_slicknav_menu`, `phpVars.ng_slicknav.prependTo`, `phpVars.ng_slicknav.label`,`phpVars.ng_slicknav.allowParentLinks` etc...

Comment: Bingo! - many thanks bonger! - prefixing the outer array did the trick, what an effort!

Comment: Good stuff, ta! I'm going to edit the answer to be more accurate...

Comment: ok good idea, I have also been told that I should escape the non boolean/integer values

Comment: Might have jumped the gun here, I still have an issue - the 2 booleans values return **true** regardless if they are set to **false**, if I look at the value direct in the db in **wp_options**, I can see it set to **false** as intended but still outputs as **true**, I have no console errors and all other fields output as intended. 

Updated Gist for example 2 - https://gist.github.com/neilgee/9bb8d424b4a0a7f2e325

Comment: I'd guess that the options are saved as string "false" and/or "true", which are always boolean true. If you save the options as boolean then it will work (and in fact, you shouldn't need casting at all).

Comment: Yes you are right - I had those options as a string as values in a select, I changed it now to a checkbox which is boolean.

So now it works perfectly with or without casting the values will be either true or false with casting or "1" or "" without