# wp_localize_script with boolean and init

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, variables, wp-localize-script

I have problem with `wp_localize_script`, That I cannot get **boolean** and **int** as variable

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'helloworld' , 'helloworld.js', false, '1.0.0', true);

$site_config = array();

$site_config['boo'] = (bool)true;
$site_config['number'] = (int)1;

wp_localize_script( 'helloworld' , 'site_config' , $site_config );
```

**Why I getting :**

```
var site_config = {"boo":"1","number":"1"};
```

**Why not :**

```
var site_config = {"boo":true,"number":1};
```

- Wordpress 4.6 *(latest)*
- PHP 5.6.10

Does not it fixed ? https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25280 , I do anything wrong or missing something ?

Comment: It's not fixed yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I just do something like this so long :**

```
wp_add_inline_script('helloworld','var site_config ='.json_encode($site_config));
```

Answer (score 3):

### *Why* part:

The *Why* part can be found within the `WP_Scripts::localize()` method:

```
foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
    if ( !is_scalar($value) )
        continue;

    $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

where we note the `(string)` casting.

### Workarounds:

The [latest proposed patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/25280/25280.5.patch) suggests replacing `is_scalar()` with `is_string()` and remove the `(string)` cast. That would work e.g. in a custom wrapper. But I don't think it's the way to go here, because the core `wp_scripts()->localize()` method can always change in the future.

I also think it's too hacky to modify the data through the methods:

```
wp_scripts()->get_data( $handle, 'data' )
```

and

```
wp_scripts()->add_data( $handle, 'data', $data )
```

Doing it properly, we might end up writing a duplicate wrapper for `wp_scripts()->localize()` ;-)

A more flexible workaround might be to use the [core function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/):

```
wp_add_inline_script( $handle, $data, $position )`
```

to add our dynamic  **non-string** values.

Answer (score 1):

If Boolean value is **true** then it will return always **1** or if Boolean value is **false** then it will return **empty** that is why you're getting **1** in case of **true**.

Below code is tested on my locally project. Copy and paste it exactly

```
//Add it in **functions.php**
function load_localize_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('localize_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/localize_script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script('localize_script', 'localize_scripts_vars', array(
                        'boolean' => true, // it will return 1 
                        'integer' => 10 // it will always return integre
            )
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_localize_scripts');

//Add this in **localize_script.js**
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var site_config;
    if (localize_scripts_vars.boolean == '1') {
        site_config = {"boolean":'true',"number":localize_scripts_vars.integer};
        console.log(site_config);
    } else if (localize_scripts_vars.boolean == '' || localize_scripts_vars.boolean == NULL) {
        site_config = {"boolean":'false',"number":localize_scripts_vars.integer};
        console.log(site_config);
    };
});
```

You can see the consol result too 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your booleans in an array, they come out clean:

```
$settings = [
  'booleans' => [
    'foo' => true,
    'bar' => false,
  ],
];
wp_localize_script('my-script-handle', 'mySettings', $settings);
```

will render:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var mySettings = {"booleans":{"foo":true;"bar":false}};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Then you can access them cleanly from your script:

```
console.log( mySettings.booleans.foo === true ); // true
console.log( mySettings.booleans.bar === false ); // true
```